# Error "package com_atlassian_clover does not exist"

Tags: java, code-coverage, clover

I am trying to use Clover to measure method code coverage for a Java project. I have installed clover-idea-4.3.1.jar (IntelliJ IDEA). The installation seems to have succeeded because all expected icons are on the toolbar. 
Next, I tried to get an instrumented build but compilation failed with multiple instances of the error: package com_atlassian_clover does not exist

what do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloverkb/noclassdeffounderror-com_atlassian_clover-coveragerecorder-317196439.html

Comment: Sadly, that kb article talks about runtime errors. this is a compilation error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution provided by @krazyk4tlady didn't work for me.

Adding this in the pom.xml solved the problem.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openclover</groupId>
        <artifactId>clover-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause for the compilation error is that IntelliJ IDEA Community 2018.2 cannot find the Clover IDEA Plugin located in C:\Users\krazyk4tlady.IntellijIDEA\config\plugins\clover-idea-4.3.1.jar -- 
The solution that works for me is to copy the JAR to another location, C:\Users\krazyk4tlady\Clover\clover-idea-4.3.1.jar then open the Project Structure dialog, go to "Platform Settings > Global Libraries, define a new global library Clover IDEA Plugin 2 pointing to the new location and add this library as a dependency to my modules.